# Why does no one seem to hit any of Mando's vulnerable spots?

Tags: star-wars, mandalorian

So Din Djarin's (Mando) Mandalorian armor has a lot of spots that the Beskar plates do not cover.
[image]

How come no one targets these areas?

They are pretty obvious if someone who was an experienced marksman (Fennick), or even just a decent shot, could hit one of these spots, injuring Mando, and slowing him down so he is easier to take down.

Or they could even hit his vulnerable neck area and take him out in one shot.

So why has no one tried shooting these areas, easily taking out a Mandalorian, and gaining their beskar?

Edit: I will accept out-of-universe answers, as long as they have evidence to back them up and follow a solid line of logic.

Comment: plot armor is made of beskar

Comment: They all went to the same shooting instructor as the Storm Troopers.

Comment: What are you implying? That fiction stories require suspension of disbelief??

Comment: Beskar actually attracts blaster bolts.

Comment: @Harabeck can you prove that?

Comment: Firestryke if anyone could hit Mando's soft spots, it's Baby Yoda. Oops, I meant Grogu.

Comment: In an actual combat situation - not just target shooting - an experienced marksman is *not* generally accurate enough to pick and choose where to hit their target. Even a standoff, like the archetypal hostage situation where people aren't really moving around, calls for a highly specialized shooter who *still* might have to aim for center mass and pray.

Comment: @Firestryke I have a feeling you perhaps didn't get that all guys before Cadence were joking...

Comment: @Mithoron It's usually difficult for me to read tones over type... Probably because there are none

Comment: @Firestryke There are no proofs in science! Hypothesis: Beskar attracts blaster bolts. Methods: Have Mando wear beskar and shoot at him with blasters. Results: 100% of hits on Mando were on the beskar. Conclusion: More research is required, but all evidence points to beskar attracting blaster fire. Experimental results were somewhat hampered by return fire from the subject, which hampered data collection. Further  ̶s̶e̶a̶s̶o̶n̶s̶ experiments are required.

Comment: Legends-wise, Mandalorian flightsuits/undersuits could be made of blaster-resistant armorweave. Boba's is described as having a "power armor liner" with some kind of basic ablative shield technology. Dooku, Grievous, and Vader all wore blaster-resistant capes in that continuity IIRC. Now *why* bad guys don't try to stab or aim between the plates or the unplated spots? Maybe the same reason they don't try shooting the bombs on his belt; too hard to hit and no guarantee it would work?

Comment: @Cadence should make an answer out of that. My son's in the (real) Army. That's what he's trained to aim for - the biggest part of the target. Also, his body armor covers the same part - center mass. He doesn't even get the benefit of leg or shoulder coverings. Hits there are pure chance and _generally_ not fatal. (Realizing that bullet <> blaster bolt.)

Comment: Ive had multiple comments on here that could have been answers, but still no one actually answers the question

Comment: @FreeMan Well, I know that holds true in the real world, but I don't actually have any good evidence that it holds true in Star Wars. At the time I hoped someone would have an in-universe source; it appears nobody did.

Comment: @Cadence I would love to see your comment being made into an answer

Comment: @Firestryke "Like a poor marksman, [they] keep...missing...the...target..." - wait...wrong franchise

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Because no one is trained to fire at limbs, for good reason.

In a firefight, combatants are trained to fire at the center of mass which is the biggest target and in most cases gives you the best chance to incapacitate/kill your target. Aiming for the exposed areas like the arms and legs requires:

1. additional skill that your average combatant wouldn't have
2. additional time to line up the shot the average combat situation wouldn't allow for and
3. additional weapons accuracy most standard weaponry wouldn't be rated for

In the real world, Dr. Bill Lewinski (executive director of the Force Science Institute) had this to say on the subject of police officers aiming for limbs instead of shooting to kill:

> "Hands and arms can be the fastest-moving body parts,” Lewinski said.
> “For example, an average suspect can move his hand and forearm across
> his body to a 90-degree angle in 12/100 of a second. He can move his
> hand from his hip to shoulder height in 18/100 of a second.
>
> "The average officer pulling the trigger as fast as he can on a Glock,
> one of the fastest- cycling semi-autos, requires 1/4 second to
> discharge each round."
>
> <sub>Pulled from [The Atlanta Journal Constitution](https://www.ajc.com/news/national/here-why-police-don-shoot-wound-the-case-deadly-force/IV4ohtIm6r8FaEMj78u1bO/)</sub>

There just isn't enough to time in a close combat situation for this tactic to be viable. So the shooter just aims at the center of mass, pulls the trigger, and hopes for the best.

You're right that there are a few vulnerable spots like the neck area but Mandalorian armor does a pretty decent job covering the most sensitive areas while still allowing the wearer a high degree of mobility. It would take the perfect angle and a fairly lucky shot.

For example, if the shooter fired from above, they'd likely hit the helmet. If they fired from the side, they'd hit the shoulders. And while I haven't noticed it directly on Din because of his cape, I know for certain other Mandos have back armor and a shot from behind would likely hit that. The shooter's best positioning would be directly in front of him and would have to be able to get the shot off without getting blasted himself by a member of a galaxy-renowned warrior race, an unlikely scenario.

And as others have noted, the areas not covered by Beskar aren't necessarily completely unprotected so we don't even know for sure that one of these miracle shots would work to take him down.

**It just isn't a viable tactic.**

Answer (score 3):

## **Those areas probably *are* armored too.**

According to [Wookieepedia's Legends entry on Mandalorian armor](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mandalorian_armor/Legends) (emphasis mine):

> Millennia later, the Mandalorian Supercommando armor was developed to
> replace the older designs which were now referred to as Mandalorian
> Shock Trooper Armor. It was no longer full body armor, but partial
> armor that left limbs almost completely undefended, and focused its
> strength on the vital areas such as the torso, head, and groin. The
> new armor was a collection of blast resistant plates, made from
> Mandalorian iron or duraplast, which were **attached to a waterproof,
> armorweave flight suit. A liner shirt with a micro energy field
> projector and two layers of ceramic plates greatly improved protection
> around the chest, back, and stomach.**

> During the Clone Wars, Jango Fett's death showed a weakpoint in the
> armor's design that would later be fixed around 20 BBY **with the
> addition of a Gorget, or collar piece, to protect the neck from rapid
> beheadings.**

The areas that you pointed out which are not covered by beskar plate are likely to still have some protection in the form of a possible combination of: an armorweave flight suit, a liner shirt with a micro energy field projector, two layers of ceramic plates, and a Gorget.  **So those areas most likely have some other form of armor and are not worth specifically targeting.**